# How to import a json file to ElasticSearch?

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I want to import a json file to ElasticSearch, however I could'nt digest how to import a json file to ElasticSearch. Please look over and iron out my view.

### The procedure I tried

First, I tried following command to execute mapping.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/library/book/_mapping' -d @mapping.json
```

The mapping.json is like this.

```
{
  "book" : {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "_index" : {
      "enabled" : true
    },
    "_id" : {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "properties" : {
      "author" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "characters" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "copies" : {
        "type" : "long",
        "ignore_malformed" : false
      },
      "otitle" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "tags" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "title" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "year" : {
        "type" : "long",
        "ignore_malformed" : false,
        "index" : "analyzed"
      },
      "available" : {
        "type" : "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The return from my console is here.

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

And then I tried this command to import documents.json to ElasticSearch

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk' --data-binary @documents.json
```

The documents.json is this.

```
{  
   "index":{  
      "_index":"library",
      "_type":"book",
      "_id":"1"
   }
}{  
   "title":"All Quiet on the Western Front",
   "otitle":"Im Westen nichts Neues",
   "author":"Erich Maria Remarque",
   "year":1929,
   "characters":[  
      "Paul Bäumer",
      "Albert Kropp",
      "Haie Westhus",
      "Fredrich Müller",
      "Stanislaus Katczinsky",
      "Tjaden"
   ],
   "tags":[  
      "novel"
   ],
   "copies":1,
   "available":true,
   "section":3
}{  
   "index":{  
      "_index":"library",
      "_type":"book",
      "_id":"2"
   }
}{  
   "title":"Catch-22",
   "author":"Joseph Heller",
   "year":1961,
   "characters":[  
      "John Yossarian",
      "Captain Aardvark",
      "Chaplain Tappman",
      "Colonel Cathcart",
      "Doctor Daneeka"
   ],
   "tags":[  
      "novel"
   ],
   "copies":6,
   "available":false,
   "section":1
}{  
   "index":{  
      "_index":"library",
      "_type":"book",
      "_id":"3"
   }
}{  
   "title":"The Complete Sherlock Holmes",
   "author":"Arthur Conan Doyle",
   "year":1936,
   "characters":[  
      "Sherlock Holmes",
      "Dr. Watson",
      "G. Lestrade"
   ],
   "tags":[  

   ],
   "copies":0,
   "available":false,
   "section":12
}{  
   "index":{  
      "_index":"library",
      "_type":"book",
      "_id":"4"
   }
}{  
   "title":"Crime and Punishment",
   "otitle":"Преступлéние и наказáние",
   "author":"Fyodor Dostoevsky",
   "year":1886,
   "characters":[  
      "Raskolnikov",
      "Sofia Semyonovna Marmeladova"
   ],
   "tags":[  

   ],
   "copies":0,
   "available":true
}
```

The return from the console is here.

```
{  
   "took":4,
   "errors":false,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "index":{  
            "_index":"library",
            "_type":"book",
            "_id":"1",
            "_version":1,
            "status":201
         }
      },
      {  
         "index":{  
            "_index":"library",
            "_type":"book",
            "_id":"2",
            "_version":1,
            "status":201
         }
      },
      {  
         "index":{  
            "_index":"library",
            "_type":"book",
            "_id":"3",
            "_version":1,
            "status":201
         }
      },
      {  
         "index":{  
            "_index":"library",
            "_type":"book",
            "_id":"4",
            "_version":1,
            "status":201
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And I tried following command.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/library/book/_search?q=title:crime&pretty=true'
```

The return from the console is here.

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.15342641,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "library",
      "_type" : "book",
      "_id" : "4",
      "_score" : 0.15342641
    } ]
  }
}
```

I could'nt point out why this returned json doesn't have '_source' key.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: What version of ES do you have and what do you see when calling this `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/library/book/1`?

Comment: thanks, when I call curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/library/book/1,

{"_index":"library","_type":"book","_id":"1","_version":10,"found":true}

and the version is 1.2.4

Comment: 1.2.4, wow that's pretty old... What happens if you add `"store": "yes"` to the `_source`  field in your mapping? You need to wipe it all, and recreate the index/mapping and re-index your data.

Comment: Excuse me for lating, and thank you so much! I got the right return that holds  '_source'!

Comment: Oh..sorry for late, I haven't got used to using stackoverflow... I accepted your  answer. I am grateful for your support!

Comment: No worries, no hurry, Kent!! Welcome on SO ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping, you need to add `"store": "yes"` in your `_source` field and it will work:

```
{
  "book" : {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": true,
      "store": "yes"                 <--- add this
    },
    "_index" : {
      "enabled" : true
    },
    "_id" : {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "properties" : {
...
```